# Angular 4 animations all elements are firing

Tags: angularjs, animation

I am trying to add an animation trigger to components generated by an `*ngFor`. The idea is to click a button and runs a method that change the animation state and flip the component related to the button.

My problem is when I click the button all the components that have the animation trigger flip. I understand why (all are using the same class property that holds the animation state)... but I can figure out how to get I need.

Here my code

`barracks.html`

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row *ngIf="playerTeamSize != undefined">
      <div [ngSwitch]="playerTeamSize" class="barrackTitle">
        <p *ngSwitchCase="-1">Finally you are here. Please pick a warrior</p>
        <p *ngSwitchCase="0">You have no team. You need at least one fighter to survive</p>
        <p *ngSwitchCase="maxTeamSize">Your team is full. Go and explore the world</p>
        <p *ngSwitchDefault>You have {{maxTeamSize - playerTeamSize}} free spots in your team. Pick another warrior</p>
      </div>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row class="characterCardWrapper">
      <ion-col class="characterCard" col-6 *ngFor="let character of characters">
        <div [@myAnimation]="animationState">
          <character-full [model]="character" (onSelected)="onSelected($event)">
          </character-full>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

`barracks.ts`

```
    import { HireCharacter } from './../../engine/D6/Character.commands';
    import { CharacterModel } from './../../components/models/character.model';
    import { HomePage } from './../home/home';
    import { Realm } from './../../engine/GameObjects/GORealm';
    import { CharacterFullComponent } from './../../components/characterFull/character-full.component';
    import { PlayerService } from './../../app/player.service';
    import { KingdomService } from './../../app/kingdom.service';
    import { TransitiveCompileNgModuleMetadata } from '@angular/compiler';
    import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Organization } from './../../engine/GameObjects/Components/Organization';
    import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-barracks',
      templateUrl: 'barracks.html',
      providers: [CharacterFullComponent],
      animations: [
        trigger('myAnimation', [
          state('idle', style({ transform: 'rotateY(0deg)'})),
          state('flip', style({ transform: 'rotateY(180deg)'})),
          transition('idle => flip', animate('2s ease-in'))
        ])
      ]
    })

    export class BarracksPage {

      characters = []
      characterIdxMap: { [name: string]: number } = {}
      wait = false
      selected = false
      playerTeamSize
      maxTeamSize = 4
      barracksFirstTime = false
      animationState = 'idle'

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private kingdom: KingdomService, private player: PlayerService) { }

      onSelected(character: any) {
        this.animationState = 'flip'
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to move the animation trigger (and code) to the component itself, so we can encapsulate the class property that triggers the animation. All good now.